# Stored prodcedure performance change

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I had performance of a stored procedure tank last night.  Looking at the query plan, the estimated row count from many of the operators is a lot higher than the actuals.  This typically signals to me that statistics are out of date.  However, after updating all statistics in all tables in the relevant database with the fullscan option, the problem persists.  I've also tried recompiling the stored procedure along with any views that it uses to no avail.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to improve the performance or why the performance changed?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did someone change the sproc?

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding or reorganizing and indexes that it is using or may be referencing?

Comment: If you look at the properties of the plan and get the compile time value of the parameters and execute with those are the cardinality estimates still wrong?

Comment: @Joe Phillips: no change to sproc. Also, running underlying query by hand produces same behavior

Comment: @Martin: I should have been more clear; the underlying query has the problem. Running it outside of the sproc behaves the same.

Comment: @Ben Thul - What does the **ACTUAL** execution plan indicate?

Comment: @Thyamine: haven't done that yet. Willing to give it a shot, though.

Comment: @Ben - Where in the plan do the cardinality errors start? (What type of construct)? @JNK - I presume the OP must be looking at the actual plan to know there is such a discrepancy anyway.

Comment: @martin - Maybe, I thought he would be looking at the rowcounts in the tables...

Comment: @JNK - Ah right. See what you mean.

Comment: @Ben - More questions!  Any views involved?  sp_refreshviews may be in order as well.  Cross DB queries?  At what point did performance drop?

Comment: Are you sure the estimated vs actual counts were different when it was performing acceptably?  What are the expensive parts of your execution plan? Any chance you could post it up?

Comment: @Martin: There are a couple of different instances, but they all seem to be coming from index seeks

Comment: @all: I was looking at an actual execution plan.  Ran the query in SSMS.

Comment: @Abe Miessler: I'm not sure of that. As to the ability to post it, I don't think I can do that.

Comment: Is your query seeking on any multi column predicates?

Answer (score 1):

Based upon what you have gone through so far, I would say take a look at your underlying data, and see if it has substantially changed in any way. Even with the most up to date statistics, queries are usually optimal for a specific range of table sizes / record return counts. Or possibly an index gone/changed somewhere in the underlying tables that would have a similar effect, drastically changing the (estimated) amount of records returned for a particular piece in the query plan.